# Why is Chrome dev tools showing me padding on visual inspector but not in the actual styles?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, padding

I'm working on the top menu on this site, http://comfortcare.wpengine.com/. There is too much padding on top of to of the menu items that I can't figure out where it's coming from or how to override it.
Chrome dev tools is showing green padding space but not padding in the actual styles.
see pic for reference.
[image: home page of the site in chrome div view, showing CSS padding.]

for reference, I am using CMS: WordPress, theme: Divi, Child theme: custom.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is to use display: table-cell
You have two divs <div id = "call_tab" style = "display: table-cell;"> with icons and <div class = "et_pb_blurb_container" style = "display: table-cell;"> with phone number and address.
If you change the table-cell on the display-block there will be magic :)

Comment: Thanks for responding @GrzegorzT. that does remove the padding but it also messes with my layout.
It also doesn't answer my question. Where are the styles coming from and why can't I see or edit them?